# How do I use Jest to test a browserify bundle of front-end code which needs a DOM API?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, browserify, jestjs, nightmare

I'm attempting to use [Nightmare](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare) to test front-end code which will eventually manipulate an SVG client-side. 
 I'm using [jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest) to write these tests.

I'm attempting to define an asynchronous utility function which I can use as an interface to [Nightmare's `evaluate`](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare#evaluatefn-arg1-arg2).

So for example, I'd like to be able to write a test like the following (modeled after [Jest's documentation of how to test asynchronous functions](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/asynchronous.html)):

```js
test("2 + 2 should be 4 in the browser", async function() {
  expect.assertions(1);
  let returnValue = await runInBrowser(function() {
  return 2 + 2;
});
  expect(returnValue).toEqual(4);
});
```

Currently, I've done this by creating a function, `runInBrowser`, which returns Nightmare's [`evaluate`](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare#evaluatefn-arg1-arg2) having been run in the context of a blank HTML page, *i.e.*

```js
runInBrowser = function(fn) {
  // Example drawn from the `visit` module imported at https://github.com/vigetlabs/jest-with-nightmare

  let page = nightmare();

  // Relying on basic `foo.html` page for testing and to offer an environment; I believe we need to `goto` a URL to have an environment to evaluate in.
  return page.goto("file://" + __dirname + "/foo.html").evaluate(fn);
};
```

where `foo.html` is a blank HTML page.

Now, with this in hand I'd like to test my code as it will run on the front-end.  I'm using [`browserify`](http://browserify.org/) to generate a bundle *via* `browserify index.js --standalone`.  I plan to then include that bundle on the front-end *via* `<script src=…>`.

**My question is this: Given that browserify will create a bundle I'd include on the front-end (say, exporting the method `foo` in a given JS file as `Bar.foo`, if my standalone bundle is `Bar`), how do I test `foo` within Nightmare?**  A unit tests of `foo` in jest, to be evaluated in the browser's context, would require me to test `Bar.foo`, but `Bar` won't have been imported into my test (even if I include `Bar` in the HTML page that my helper function opens).

This all feels quite messy for what I assume is a very common need: using jest to unit test browserified code that must be run in a browser context.  So, I assume I'm doing something wrong.  Any advice (or pointers to samples or templates) would be appreciated.